# Jquery background colour change animate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background of an inputbox from white to another colour and then back to white again in a slow fading way. i have tried the animate it simply doesn't work. there is no error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/ui/jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
...
$(document.getElementById(id)).animate({ backgroundColor: "#4E1402" }, 500);
```

**update**

This works fine

```
$(document.getElementById(id)).animate({ width: "400px" }, 500);
```

Comment: Try `$('#' + id).animate({ backgroundColor: "#4E1402" }, 500);` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery cannot animate color. Use this plugin instead.

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

( just a 4kb addition )

Or the jquery UI animate :

http://jqueryui.com/animate/   ( as mentioned by @Adam below )

Comment: Or the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/), which uses this plugin: [https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/)

Answer (score 0):

You need this plugin to animate the colors with jQuery :
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Answer (score 0):

Have you included jquery-ui library as well?

If I remember good, current element that you are reffering to, must have some background color set at start.