# Slow colour changing background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a background on a website slowly change colour, so constantly from red, to green, to blue, back to red. Is there a way with jQuery or JavaScript to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Look down the right hand side of this page, all of those are (pretty much) dupes of this question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery background colour change animate not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814767/jquery-background-colour-change-animate-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

For simple animations you can use CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation:  changeBgColor 3s infinite;
  -moz-animation:     changeBgColor 3s infinite;
  -ms-animation:      changeBgColor 3s infinite;
  -o-animation:       changeBgColor 3s infinite;
  animation:          changeBgColor 3s infinite;
}    

@-webkit-keyframes changeBgColor {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes changeBgColor {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes changeBgColor {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes changeBgColor {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

keyframes changeBgColor {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

[JS Bin Example](http://jsbin.com/pujaho/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
var color = "red"    
setInterval(function() {
    if(color == "red") {
         $('body').stop().animate({backgroundColor: "green"}, 2000);
         color = "green";
    } else if(color == "green") {
         $('body').stop().animate({backgroundColor: "blue"}, 2000);
         color = "blue";
    } else if(color == "blue") {
        $('body').stop().animate({backgroundColor: "red"}, 2000);
        color = "red";
    }
}, 2500);
```